# Make all functions strict mode literal object?

Tags: javascript, object, literals, mode, strict

Let's say we have this script.

```
var apple = {
    type: "macintosh",
    color: "red",
    getInfo: function () {
        return this.color + ' ' + this.type + ' apple';
    }
    ///more functions here....
}
```

How can I let all these functions run in strict mode? I can put "use strict" at the top of the file but JSlint does not approve this. An alternative is to put "use strict" in every function, but is there a better option?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap everything inside an IIFE and JSLint should approve.

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    //all your code here
}());
```

---

Note that variables/functions previously declared in the global scope would no longer be accessible in the global scope when moved to inside this immediately-invoked function expression.

You will have to explicitly set these as properties of the global object, e.g. the `window` object for browser environment:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    window.someGlobalVariable = "something";
}());
```

**@zzzzBov**'s solution also works nicely on both browser and back-end environments.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap everything in an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/), alias the global reference, and explicitly set global variables on the global object:

```
(function (root) { //could be window (browser), could be global (node)
    "use strict";
    ...code...
    root.apple = apple; //explicitly make apple a global variable
}(this));
```

Comment: +1 for addressing the global vars, this is an easily overlooked quirk. Though I do apply IIFE wrappers to virtually all of my scripts.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using namespaces for your object literals, I like this approach best:

```
(function (myApp) {
    'use strict';

    myApp.myObj = {
        init: function(){}           
    }

}(window.myApp = window.myApp || {}));

myApp.myObj.init();
```